# Do no reset TrackingId Kinect when user left screen C#

Tags: c#, kinect

In my situation i track bodies with Kinect Sensor with `body.TrackingId`
and after on each body i draw a skeleton in different color.

But when an user left the screen and come back a new id is assigned to this player and i can't take the old id.

This situation is very problematic because: if a player go ahead another player the id of the second player will be lost.

Can someone know who i can to to recognize if it was a same player without giving a new `TrackingId`

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I dont thinks this is possible. Every time the sensor assigns new ID's. The only think i can think of is if you track depending on the color. Using a framework like Aforge.