# Kinect V2 SDK 2 re-identify bodies

Tags: kinect, kinect-sdk

Is there a way to re-identify bodies, which exit the scene and re-enter it?
The SDK 2 gives new IDs on re-enter.
Is there a library for that? Or is it practicable to save body data (length of arm, etc.) and compare it to the bodies re-entering?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do no reset TrackingId Kinect when user left screen C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958915/do-no-reset-trackingid-kinect-when-user-left-screen-c-sharp)

Comment: Yeah.. this feature would be important but thus far no one was able to deal with it

Answer (score 0):

You would have to generate your own method of locally tracking body information on a PC the Kinect is hooked up to. You would need to set up an analysis feature where the person stands in a fixed position and either use facial recognition or measure their bodies and find the closest matching data. Then you can temporarily assign the data to the body IDs and use that to track them while they are in view.
There is no way to keep track of a body if they leave the view without going through the processes of analyzing and comparing the body or face.